# SUM a column in SQL, based on DISTINCT values in another column, GROUP BY a third column

Tags: sql, sum, distinct

I'd appreciate some help on the following SQL problem:

I have a table of 3 columns:

```
ID    Group    Value
1     1        5
1     1        5
1     2        10    
1     2        10
1     3        20
2     1        5
2     1        5
2     1        5
2     2        10
2     2        10
3     1        5
3     2        10
3     2        10
3     2        10
3     4        50
```

I need to group by ID, and I would like to SUM the values based on DISTINCT values in Group. So the value for a group is only accounted for once even though it may appear multiple for times for a particular ID.

So for IDs 1, 2 and 3, it should return 35, 15 and 65, respectively.

```
ID    SUM
1     35
2     15
3     65
```

Note that each Group doesn't necessarily have a unique value

Thanks

Comment: Break it into two steps: 1) write a inline view which gets distinct values (`Select distinct ID, Group, Value FROM TABLE`). 2) using that as a CTE or inline view, write your aggregation on it.  `Select ID, group, sum(value) from (inlineview) Group by ID, GROUP`.  If you have trouble based on this post what you're struggling with and we can help.  as it stands this is just a "get distinct values" then aggregates.  Note: group is a reserved word so you may need to escape it.

Comment: Update your example to show this and explain what you would want to have happen.  As your example doesn't show this and you've not given sufficient rules to explain what should happen then.

Comment: Can you share the expected output and your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: "Note that each Group doesn't necessarily have a unique value... " What does this mean?  provide an example.  for each ID and group, the value appears to be duplicated and when distinct is applied, would be unique...   If that's not the case, please provide an example where it is not true.

Comment: I'm really lost in terms of coding this. I have now included the expected output. A group's value is always the same, but a value is not unique to a group. For example groups 6 and 7 could have a value of 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what we know at the moment this is what I'm thinking...

The CTE/Inline view eliminate duplicates before the sum occurs.

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT DISTINCT ID, Group, Value FROM TableName)
SELECT ID, Sum(Value)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ID
```

or

```
SELECT ID, Sum(Value)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TableName) CTE
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 2):

the CTE will remove all duplicates, so if there a sdiffrenet values for ID and Group, it will be counted.

The next SELECT wil "GROUP By" ID

For Pstgres you would get

> ```
> WITH CTE as
> (SELECT DISTINCT "ID", "Group", "Value" FROM tablA
> )
> SELECT "ID", SUM("Value") FROM CTE GROUP BY "ID"
> ORDER BY "ID"
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | sum
> -: | --:
>  1 |  35
>  2 |  15
>  3 |  65
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=77bb8ec6a34cd97efae2693ecbd43573)*